# Is there a vehicle larger than a van that is used about a news station vehicle?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

We had a small news van while they had a large _______________.

Is there a vehicle larger than a van that is used about a news station vehicle? Is a news truck basically the same as a news van? What about a news bus? Is that used?

Comment: The divisions between *van, truck, bus* are arbitrary and imprecise. If you want to convey that the vehicle you're talking about is *larger* than the average "news van" (whatever that means to you), you can call it a "news truck" if you like. And to convey that it *holds more people* than the "standard" vehicle, you can call it a "news bus". But none of these terms have fixed definitions, so it's basically a matter of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A "news bus" doesn't sound to me like a vehicle containing production/broadcast equipment. It sounds more like a metaphor, like "bandwagon." I agree with everything else you said but I can't recommend using this phrase. News truck is fine.

Comment: I must admit when I went to check [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+news+van%2Ca+news+truck%2Ca+news+wagon%2Ca+news+bus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20news%20van%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20news%20truck%3B%2Cc0), I was expecting to see ***news wagon*** at least in the running, if not actually more common than ***news truck***. The former is [far from unknown](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+news+wagon%22), but it's not common enough to show on an NGram chart.

Answer (score 1):

There are news trucks. They generally aren't much bigger than news vans, we're talking the difference between, well, literally a van and a box truck. The big exception are the full broadcast equipment trucks used for broadcasting sports and other major events where you need on-premise directors and staff. There's pretty much zero need for those big trucks for regular on-location reporting.

Comment: Note that 'truck' is mainly American usage. I have seen vehicles called 'trucks' in the US that I would call a 'large van', and what Americans call a 'minivan' we in the UK would call a 'people mover'.